# Morris Line Chart with 2 Y axis

Tags: javascript, json, html, morris.js

I have the data in below format:

```
| Date...................| Execution Time........ | Count ......... |
|:-----------------------|-----------------------:|:---------------:|
| 12-07-15 10:30 AM      | .................10... | ....3000....... |
| 12-07-15 10:40 AM      | .................20... | ....4230....... |
| 12-07-15 10:55 AM      | ................542... | ..127896....... |
| 12-07-15 12:40 PM      | .................32... | ....2313....... |
```

I am trying to keep a line chart which shows the Date in X axis and Execution Time and Count in the Y axis.

But I am unable to do this.  I wanted something like the below link using Morris Line chart.

[Linechart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS)#/media/File:AppleAppStoreStatistics.png)

Can someone help me with it? I can do a one-sided line chart but I'm not sure how to have a char with 2 Y axes.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no built-in functionality to accomplish this, though [it is a very highly-requested feature](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/113).

If you really need two y-axes on the same graph, you will either have to rely on some ugly hacks or a different graphing solution.  As far as ugly hacks go, you could overlay two graphs, chopping one up to place the y-axis on the right side.  It won't be pretty, but it might just work.

Comment: It has been few years. Now does it support multiple Y-axis?

Comment: I recently gave up on Morris. I recently switched to ChartJS which appears to be well supported and actively maintained: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html